# What does the $wp_did_header do in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

What does the **$wp_did_header** variable do in wordpress in wp-blog-header.php file?
And why is it setted to **true**?

Comment: Please use google... it is a simply question...

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20616/whats-the-purpose-of-wp-did-header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [global variable](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/a1bd091d6591cff669957b80d155f054ff7cd994/wp-includes/template.php#L486) that can be used to check whether or not WordPress has already sent headers.